# fastapi - firebase authentication with JWT's?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, fastapi

I'm trying to use fastapi to return some basic ML models to users.

Currently, I secure user details with firebase auth. I want to use the JWT's users have when using the basic application to authenticate their request for the ML model.

With fastapi, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward answer to doing this.

I've followed two main threads as ways to work out how to do this, but am a bit lost as to how I can simply take the JWT from the header of a request and check it against firebase admin or whathave you?

Following this tutorial and using this package, I end up with something like this,
https://github.com/tokusumi/fastapi-cloudauth . This doesn't really do anything - it doesn't authenticate the JWT for me, bit confused as to if this package is actually worthwhile?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Header,Depends
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.security import HTTPAuthorizationCredentials, HTTPBearer
from fastapi_cloudauth.firebase import FirebaseCurrentUser, FirebaseClaims

app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBearer()


origins = [
    xxxx
]

app.add_middleware(
   xxxx

)

get_current_user = FirebaseCurrentUser(
    project_id=os.environ["PROJECT_ID"]
)


@app.get("/user/")
def secure_user(current_user: FirebaseClaims = Depends(get_current_user)):
    # ID token is valid and getting user info from ID token
    return f"Hello, {current_user.user_id}"
```

Alternatively, looking at this,

https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4768

It seems like something like this would work,

```
security = HTTPBearer()

api = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBearer()

firebase_client = FirebaseClient(
    firebase_admin_credentials_url=firebase_test_admin_credentials_url
    # ...
)

user_roles = [test_role]

async def firebase_authentication(token: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(security)) -> dict:
    user = firebase_client.verify_token(token.credentials)
    return user

async def firebase_authorization(user: dict = Depends(firebase_authentication)):
    roles = firebase_client.get_user_roles(user)

    for role in roles:
        if role in user_roles:
            return user

    raise HTTPException(detail="User does not have the required roles", status_code=HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN)

@api.get("/")
async def root(uid: str = Depends(firebase_authorization)):
    return {"message": "Successfully authenticated & authorized!"}
```

But honestly I'm a bit confused about how I would set up the firebase environment variables, what packages I would need (firebaseadmin?)

Would love some helpers, thanks!

Comment: What outcome do you get from your first try? (using `fastapi_cloudauth.firebase`?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope this will help:

1. Create functions to work with Firebase admin, create credentials from Firebase as JSON file:

```
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status, Response
from firebase_admin import auth, credentials, initialize_app

credential = credentials.Certificate('./key.json')
initialize_app(credential)

def get_user_token(res: Response, credential: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials=Depends(HTTPBearer(auto_error=False))):
    if cred is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Bearer authentication is needed",
            headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer realm="auth_required"'},
        )
    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(credential.credentials)
    except Exception as err:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail=f"Invalid authentication from Firebase. {err}",
            headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer error="invalid_token"'},
        )
    res.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Bearer realm="auth_required"'
    return decoded_token
```

2. Then put it inside your FastAPI main function:

```
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status, Response, FastAPI, Depends
from firebase_admin import auth, credentials, initialize_app

credential = credentials.Certificate('./key.json')
initialize_app(credential)

def get_user_token(res: Response, credential: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials=Depends(HTTPBearer(auto_error=False))):
    if cred is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Bearer authentication is needed",
            headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer realm="auth_required"'},
        )
    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(credential.credentials)
    except Exception as err:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail=f"Invalid authentication from Firebase. {err}",
            headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer error="invalid_token"'},
        )
    res.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Bearer realm="auth_required"'
    return decoded_token

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/api/")
async def hello():
    return {"msg":"Hello, this is API server"} 


@app.get("/api/user_token")
async def hello_user(user = Depends(get_user_token)):
    return {"msg":"Hello, user","uid":user['uid']}
```

P.S. Do not forget to install requirements:
`pip3 install firebase_admin`

Comment: Thanks @bauyrzhan, this is exactly what I needed. Is there a typo though in `get_user_token`? Should it be:

`if credential is None:`

in get_user_token

Comment: Hello, maybe, sorry it was long time ago when I have written that answer.